# Why Delayed choice quantum eraser doesn't produce two lines

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

As I understand, a Double slit experiment produces interference pattern or two broad distributions on the detector based on observation.

Does delayed choice quantum eraser produces the same patterns ?

I think the question it comes down to is: when we have a double slit experiment, can we look at the pattern on the screen and tell from it if the observer is present or not? From the videos I got impression like "O, there is an interference pattern, means no one is watching"; "No interference pattern = someone is watching/measurement is being made". But why does it sound like in case of delayed choice quantum eraser, the screen will look the same no matter what.

My impression is that the quantum eraser is also a double slit experiment, but with entanglement part that effectively makes a copy of the information.

Please help me, I really need those lottery numbers

Comment: It doesn't come out as two lines - it needs to come out as two broad distributions that overlap each other. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/480062/can-post-selecting-on-the-screen-in-the-delayed-choice-quantum-eraser-experiment/ for plots of what the different distributions look like.

Comment: More generally, though, it really isn't clear what you're asking here.

Comment: I have updated my question.